# Applying a mask to a Bitmap in-situ

Tags: android, bitmap, mask

I am attempting to apply an Oval/Round mask to a mutable bitmap in the most memory efficient manner I can. The input bitmap is in ARGB_8888 format. My intention was to draw an Oval/Circle into a ALPH_8 bitmap and then use the resulting bitmap as a mask over the input bitmap. The code I have is as follows:

```
protected final static RectF rectF = new RectF();
protected final static Rect rect = new Rect();
protected final static Paint ovalPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
protected final static Paint maskPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
static {
maskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
}
/**
 * Apply oval mask to bitmap
 * 
 * @param srcImage
 *            reference to bitmap image to which mask is applied
 * @return reference to resulting bitmap (may be same as bitmap passed)
 */
private Bitmap applyImageMAsk(Bitmap srcImage) {
final int width = srcImage.getWidth();
final int height = srcImage.getHeight();

Bitmap mask = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ALPHA_8);
final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mask);

rect.right = width;
rect.bottom = height;
rectF.set(rect);

canvas.drawOval(rectF, ovalPaint);
**//mask = mask.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, false);**

canvas.setBitmap(srcImage);
canvas.drawBitmap(mask, rect, rect, maskPaint);

return srcImage;
}
```

This does not work, no mask is applied. If however I uncomment the mask.copy line, effectively producing am ARGB_8888 copy of the oval mask, it works perfectly. Obviously just using an ALPHA_8 bit map would be far more memory efficient and I would like to understand why this does not work.

Comment: try Canvas.saveLayer()

Comment: As I understand it, using saveLayer allocates an off screen buffer! Would this not defeat my aim of minimising memory usage?

Comment: this is not a "normal" buffer like a Bitmap, its a GPU layer,  for example in v2.* android used that buffer to draw every step of AlphaAnimation,  so if it were drawn in 20 frames saveLayer was called 20 times in fractions of second